# Java threading callback thread context

Tags: java, multithreading, callback, activemq-classic

How do I ensure the callback is called within the context of the main thread?

I'm using ActiveMQ and specifically, I'm trying to understand how to ensure a callback is executed within the context of the thread that created the activemq consumer.

The thread ID I get in the listener/handler is different from the one that created the consumer and set the listener, so I'm trying to understand how I can ensure my code in the handler/listener runs on the first thread thread.

If I had created the thread which runs the code in the listener, I probably would have used Executor and Future, but since it was created for me by activemq, I was hoping to figure out how to get the listener to execute within the context of the 'main' thread.

I then started reading about java threading callbacks in general, and most articles explain calling a method on a class you pass into the thread that implements runnable.  It seems to me that any code in that callback will still be within the context of the thread I just spawned.

..so how do I ensure the callback is called within the context of the main thread?

In .net I could use the SynchronizationContext or in WPF the Dispatcher which uses this context under the hood..

I've been looking at synchronized methods but it looks like those methods access data variables defined in another thread, ie the 'main' thread where in my case, the variables/data are created in the consumer thread and I need to pass them back / ensure they are available on the 'main' thread.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting problem. The first thing I would do is make sure I knew what thread is executing. A simple way is to put this print statement in the callback:
System.out.println(Thread.currentThread());

Now as far as making a method run on a particular thread: Don't think so. Getting a thread's context is not part of Java. Unlike .Net, the JVM may be written by different companies. IBM as a really good one. JRocket from Oracle is another. So getting under the hood is not so easy.

I'll poke around some more and let you know what if find.

Comment: Thanks, I mean it's not a problem per se, it's more of the correct way to execute work when results come back on a different thread. The reason I asked is two fold: 1. I didn't want to overwhelm the consumer thread with work that should be done on another thread, leaving the consumer to focus on incoming messages and 2. who should orchestrate what to do next and where it's executed. I was thinking the main thread would be responsible for that, spawning another thread to perform work, passing in the results received from the consumer thread.

Comment: Perhaps that's a bad idea because the main thread could still be busy doing something and block the consumer thread as its not ready to receive results.

Comment: You could have your callback logic start a new thread or wake up an existing work thread to do the heavy lifting. I've used that technique.

Comment: From what I can tell I have two options.. 1. as edharned mentioned, I can spawn up a thread to do work and pass the results in there, be it raw or using executor/future to ensure the work is async and not blocking the consumer or 2. I can have a separate thread (a scheduler) which has a synchronized collection of work items. It is woken up when an item is added so that it can use the executor to fire it off or when that executed tasks finishes and comes back so that it can determine whether or not it can fire off the next task.

Comment: Using a separate sub-system with a blocking queue is a fine option, a lot cleaner then a single thread waking up. Go for it.